# managing publish profiles for mvc application

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, publish-profiles

I am developing an MVC 4 web application, VS2012.

For such applications I normally created an msi to install the app but for this project I am moving to the more modern publishing mechanism. I normally install to different environments:

- dev
- qa (server 1, 2, 3)
- staging
- prod (server 1, 2, 3)

Question is, do I need to create a publish profile for each of the environments, including a profile for each of the servers on qa and prod (as 1 web config setting varies between servers).

It seems like a need to create alot of publish profiles for this. Am I correct? What is the best way to manage publish profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Publish profiles were designed for what you are describing.  They allow you to specify different publishing configurations on a per server basis.

I am not sure what you mean by `What is the best way to manage the publish profiles?`.  VS 2012.2 will manage these for you within the solution.

You can also right click on a publish profile and add a web config transform for that specific publish profile.

Sayed Hashimi has a good video explaining this here. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdPK8mxpKEI